# Alter command along with Default key

Tags: mysql, database, alter

I wanted to add **Default** to an existing column through alter command ,

```
alter table Student_Details modify column Student_Class enum('First','Second','Third') Default '{1}' ;
```

Is there any way to do it.

Comment: Well, do you see `{1}` in the declaration of `enum('First','Second','Third')`? No? Then this is your error.

Comment: @fancyPants  i get error while using default keyword for an Alter command,    "alter table Student_Details modify column Student_Class int Not Null default '{1}'  "

Answer (score 0):

The point of the enum datatype is to allow only certain values in a column. In your case that's `'First'`, `'Second'` and `'Third'`. Therefore you can not assign `'{1}'` as default value. You may have heard, that you can also use the index of each value in an enum, but then use `1` and not `'1'` and certainly not `{1}`. The `'` make it a string and not a number and the `{}` is just not valid syntax. Actually I haven't tried to assign a default value with the index, I don't know if it's valid at all. Actually I avoid enum like poison, [here](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/) are some reasons for it.

Anyway, make it

```
alter table Student_Details modify column Student_Class enum('First','Second','Third') Default 'First';
```

and it should work.